# Merging 2 ordered sets preserving order of each set

Tags: combinatorics

There are 2 separate event chains.

The first event chain is: `[A, B, C]`

The second event chain is: `[1, 2, 3]`

You cannot change the order of events in a chain. They both must be ordered as `[1, 2, 3]` and `[A, B, C]`.

Now we want to combine 2 event chains while preserving the order of each chain.

Like `[A, 1, B, 2, C, 3]` or `[A, 1, 2, 3, B, C]`.

As you can see, we may have lots of combinations. My question is, how many combinations are there to have?

PS: I'm not a mathematician, this problem came to my mind while studying evolution. The evolution of species must be ordered, for example, we had a single cell organism first, then multi-cell organisms. Considering there may be multiple species having their own course of evolution, their evolution order does not change but when you think about multiple species, although their order does not change, the order which one came first can be changed. TLDR: this is a real problem I was curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really just need to choose which 3 out of the 6 positions contains an element of [A, B, C].

e.g. if we choose 1, 2, and 5 the sequence will be
[A, B, 1, 2, C, 3]

so the total number of sequences is just...
$$ N =\binom 63 = 20$$

Answer (score 2):

Let there be $n$ elements in the first list and $m$ in the second.  The combined list will have $m+n$ elements and is completely determined by the positions of the elements of the first list.  So there are $$\binom{n+m}{n}$$ possibilities.